# Thingsboard installation 3.4.4 to 3.5 Fails schema udpate: PostgreSQL relation and column do not exist

Tags: postgresql, upgrade, thingsboard

When upgrading from Thingsboard 3.4.4PE to 3.5PE the schema update fails:

```
...
Updating schema ...
Failed updating schema!!!
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "entity_alarm" does not exist
...
Unexpected error during ThingsBoard installation!
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column a.assignee_id does not exist
  Position: 3327
...
```

Thingsboard 3.4.4PE was running well, and I do not know how to identify the issue.  While the suggestions [here](https://github.com/thingsboard/thingsboard/issues/6971) might be useful, I cannot determine my password to access PostgreSQL directly.

Thank you for any suggestions.

The upgrade.sh command used:

```
sudo /usr/share/thingsboard/bin/install/upgrade.sh --fromVersion=3.4.4
```

and the full output after a second run of the command:

```
  ______    __      _                              ____                               __
 /_  __/   / /_    (_)   ____    ____ _   _____   / __ )  ____   ____ _   _____  ____/ /
  / /     / __ \  / /   / __ \  / __ `/  / ___/  / __  | / __ \ / __ `/  / ___/ / __  /
 / /     / / / / / /   / / / / / /_/ /  (__  )  / /_/ / / /_/ // /_/ /  / /    / /_/ /
/_/     /_/ /_/ /_/   /_/ /_/  \__, /  /____/  /_____/  \____/ \__,_/  /_/     \__,_/
                              /____/

 ===================================================
 :: ThingsBoard Professional Edition ::       (v3.5.0PE)
 ===================================================

Starting ThingsBoard Upgrade from version 3.4.4 ...
Clearing cache to upgrade from version 3.4.4 to 3.5.0
Clearing cache [deviceProfiles]
Upgrading ThingsBoard from version 3.4.4 to 3.5.0 ...
Updating schema ...
Failed updating schema!!!
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "entity_alarm" does not exist
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2676)
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2366)
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:356)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:496)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:413)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeWithFlags(PgStatement.java:333)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeCachedSql(PgStatement.java:319)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeWithFlags(PgStatement.java:295)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:290)
        at org.thingsboard.server.service.install.SqlDatabaseUpgradeService.loadSql(SqlDatabaseUpgradeService.java:873)
        at org.thingsboard.server.service.install.SqlDatabaseUpgradeService.upgradeDatabase(SqlDatabaseUpgradeService.java:703)
        at org.thingsboard.server.install.ThingsboardInstallService.performInstall(ThingsboardInstallService.java:270)
        at org.thingsboard.server.ThingsboardInstallApplication.main(ThingsboardInstallApplication.java:66)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:108)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.PropertiesLauncher.main(PropertiesLauncher.java:467)
Upgrading ThingsBoard from version 3.5.0 to 3.5.0PE ...
Updating schema ...
relation "entity_group" already exists, skipping
relation "converter" already exists, skipping
relation "integration" already exists, skipping
relation "scheduler_event" already exists, skipping
relation "blob_entity" already exists, skipping
relation "role" already exists, skipping
relation "group_permission" already exists, skipping
relation "device_group_ota_package" already exists, skipping
relation "converter_debug_event" already exists, skipping
relation "integration_debug_event" already exists, skipping
relation "raw_data_event" already exists, skipping
relation "idx_entity_group_by_type_name_and_owner_id" already exists, skipping
relation "idx_converter_external_id" already exists, skipping
relation "idx_integration_external_id" already exists, skipping
relation "idx_role_external_id" already exists, skipping
relation "idx_entity_group_external_id" already exists, skipping
relation "idx_converter_debug_event_main" already exists, skipping
relation "idx_integration_debug_event_main" already exists, skipping
relation "idx_raw_data_event_main" already exists, skipping
Schema updated.
Installing SQL DataBase schema views and functions: schema-views-and-functions.sql
Unexpected error during ThingsBoard installation!
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column a.assignee_id does not exist
  Position: 3327
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2676)
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2366)
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:356)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:496)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:413)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeWithFlags(PgStatement.java:333)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeCachedSql(PgStatement.java:319)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeWithFlags(PgStatement.java:295)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:290)
        at org.thingsboard.server.service.install.SqlAbstractDatabaseSchemaService.executeQueryFromFile(SqlAbstractDatabaseSchemaService.java:97)
        at org.thingsboard.server.service.install.SqlEntityDatabaseSchemaService.createOrUpdateViewsAndFunctions(SqlEntityDatabaseSchemaService.java:68)
        at org.thingsboard.server.install.ThingsboardInstallService.performInstall(ThingsboardInstallService.java:274)
        at org.thingsboard.server.ThingsboardInstallApplication.main(ThingsboardInstallApplication.java:66)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:108)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.PropertiesLauncher.main(PropertiesLauncher.java:467)
Unexpected error during ThingsBoard installation!
ThingsBoard upgrade failed!
```

Answer (score 0):

The [upgrade instructions](https://thingsboard.io/docs/user-guide/install/upgrade-instructions/#upgrading-to-344) for 3.4.4 are missing the the instructions to run the upgrade script. The following upgrade command is required: `/usr/share/thingsboard/bin/install/upgrade.sh --fromVersion=3.4.3` For some reason, 3.4.4 works fine without this schema upgrade, but 3.5 fails.

This is how to run the upgrade script manually:

```
sudo -Hiu postgres bash
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/thingsboard/thingsboard/cb37450470892f82a3787a1e989f3463295f1055/application/src/main/data/upgrade/3.4.4/schema_update.sql

psql thingsboard --file=schema_update.sql
```